# Doesn't appear the actual error through command line in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to create an HTTP server with GET and POST, using Node.js, the user will upload images and archives. But the problem is that while trying to run the server, the command line from Node.js don't show to me the actual error, and point out to some line that doesn't exist.

**Server.js**

```
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http"); 
var formidable = require("formidable");


function start(route ,handle) {
function onRequest(request, response) { 
    var postData = "";
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");      

    request.setEncoding("utf8");

    request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) { 
        postData += postDataChunk;
        console.log("Received POST data chunk ' " + 
            postDataChunk + " ' .");
    });

request.addListener("data", function(chunk) {
    //called when a new chunk of data was received
});

request.addListener("end", function() {
    //called when all chunks of data been received
});

    request.addListener("end", function() {
    route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
    });
}

    var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    sys = require('sys');

    http.createServer(function(req,res) {
        if(req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'POST') {
            //parse a file upload
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/plain'});
                res.write('received upload \n\n');
                res.end(sys.inspect({fields : fields, files : files}));
            });
            return;
        }


        //show a file upload form
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
        res.end(
        '<form action = "/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" ' +
        'method ="post">' +
        '<input type="text" name= "title" ><br>' +
        '<input type ="file" name = "upload" multiple="multiple"<br>' +
        '<input typw="submit" value="upload"' +
        '</form>');
}).listen(8888);


exports.start = start;
```

The only thing for sure is that I know that is happening in `Server.js` because is pointed out to there.

> server.js:69 - Unexpected token )

How can I get to know where this error is ? And maybe can be a lot of other sintax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing `}` for the `start` function. Try adding that in and see if the error goes away. This is how your code should look (with correct indents to make it easier to spot errors):

```
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http"); 
var formidable = require("formidable");

function start(route ,handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) { 
        var postData = "";
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");      

        request.setEncoding("utf8");

        request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) { 
            postData += postDataChunk;
            console.log("Received POST data chunk ' " + 
                postDataChunk + " ' .");
        });

        request.addListener("data", function(chunk) {
            //called when a new chunk of data was received
        });

        request.addListener("end", function() {
            //called when all chunks of data been received
        });

        request.addListener("end", function() {
        route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
        });
    }

    var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    sys = require('sys');

    http.createServer(function(req,res) {
        if(req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'POST') {
            //parse a file upload
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/plain'});
                res.write('received upload \n\n');
                res.end(sys.inspect({fields : fields, files : files}));
            });
            return;
        }

        //show a file upload form
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
        res.end(
        '<form action = "/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" ' +
        'method ="post">' +
        '<input type="text" name= "title" ><br>' +
        '<input type ="file" name = "upload" multiple="multiple"<br>' +
        '<input typw="submit" value="upload"' +
        '</form>');
    }).listen(8888);
}

exports.start = start;
```

Comment: Don't work too, when I put the } he points out to him, and says that he is not expected. I don't know what is happening here, I tried everything, change the code, commenting some part of the code, but it doesn't change anything, just the line where the error is.

Comment: @Monteiro Where did you put the bracket? The bracket is definitely missing in the example code you pasted and there's nothing else wrong with the syntax, so if it's complaining after you add the bracket then you've put it in the wrong place.

Comment: @Monteiro Wait, why do you require `http` and `formidable` twice?

Comment: I just saw this now, in fact I don't need. Just going to remove that part.

Comment: Thank you, it worked now. Can't vote to +1 for now, but I can mark your answer as the more helpful.

Comment: @Monteiro Awesome, glad you got it working! :D Still not sure why Node decided to report the wrong line number, but whatever, it works now :P